# Solr : Can post.jar be used to post files recursively within folder and subfolder

Tags: post, solr, document

If I would like to post all the xml files in a folder then I use post.jar.

> java -jar post.jar *.xml

In case if I would like to post the files recursively ( i.e post xml files under subfolder level also is there anyway to achieve this.)

Answer (score 3):

If you're on a unix-like (OSX or Linux), you can do something like this:

```
find . -name \*xml | xargs java -jar post.jar
```

That'll find all .xml files in or under the current directory ('.') and pass them as parameters to the `java -jar post.jar` command.

`find` is incredibly opaque, but very useful for stuff like this.

Comment: Hi I m running my application on Windows platform. Is there anyway to achieve this without the use of Cygwin. May be some command.

Answer (score 0):

Please think twice before using stuff under the **/example** directory of Solr. I use Solr from Tomcat (instead of the Jetty embedded in the **start.jar**) and I use URLLIB2 in Python for POSTing data to Solr. (Jetty is a production-level software, so dont worry too much about that).

So, for uploading files, consider **writing it in your favorite programming language**. You can implement folder recursion yourself. For POSTing files, you need  [libCURL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) , which can send HTTP GET, form POSTs, multipart POSTs etc. A C program using libCURL needs no more than 8 lines to POST a file. CURL bindings exist for all major languages, so you can recycle libCURL stuff written in C to PHP, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can!

You just need to ad the -Drecursive flag.

```
java -Drecursive -jar post.jar *
```

For further options for the flags and usage just use:

```
java -jar post.jar -h
```